# azcopy login not granting permissions

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azcopy

I want to use `azcopy` to download/upload to my blob storage.

Using `azcopy login`, opening the browser and login works fine.

```
$ azcopy login --tenant-id xxxx
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code xxx to authenticate.

INFO: Login succeeded.
```

Now I am trying:

```
$ azcopy ls https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx

failed to obtain credential info: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public
```

The container access level is set to private, the authentication method set to Azure AD User Account and I am Storage Blob Data Owner and Owner.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Please ensure that you have logged in first while you are performing the `azcopy list` operation .***

***I tested the same scenario in my environment by creating a storage account , a private container with Azure AD authentication enabled and having owner and storage blob data owner role like below :***

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

***The error only occurs when I have either logged out or haven't logged in to azcopy like below :***

[image]

**Update:**

If the above doesn't resolve the issue the you can use `keyctl session workaroundSession` first and then use `azcopy login` and other commands as mentioned in this ***[`GitHub Issue`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/452) by John Rusk***

Comment: Still didn't work. But I realized `azcopy logout` didn't work either, which lead me to this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/452. Following the instructions in that bug ticket worked.

Comment: Thanks @marcopah, added the same to answer as well